# Is it possible to load an external JS script into a blob?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

I'm currently toying around with Workers and they're pretty neat, but one thing's certainly missing: The possibility to pass the Worker an anonymous function. Because I had some free time on my hands, I wanted to see if I could figure out a solution to this problem. I thought that the most obvious way to do achieve this would be using [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob) and hence I set up this little script:

```
var blob = new Blob(['var getLastSeen = function(player) { \
                    $.getJSON("fetch.php?player=" + player, function(data){ \
                        if(data.online) \
                            postMessage("online"); \
                        else if(data.online == false) \
                            postMessage(data.lastSeen); \
                    }); \
                    };\
                    getLastSeen("AI@speedersclan.org");'],{ "type" : "text\/javascript" });

var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

worker.onmessage = function (Event) {
    document.getElementById("logDisplay").innerText = Event.data;
};
```

(getLastSeen does a database lookup to see when was the last time the player logged in)

As you probably noticed I need jQuery to run this script and therefore I thought I'd just add this little chunk of code at the beginning of the Blob:

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; \ 
var script = document.createElement("script"); \
script.type= "text/javascript"; \
script.src= "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"; \
head.appendChild(script); \
```

What I didn't notice, although I immediately should have, after looking at the type of the Blob, is that there's no way to interact with the DOM, which means loading an external script is obviously not possible (at least with the method I am using).

(tl;dr) So my question is, "How do I load an external script into a blob, although I can't interact with the DOM"?

**edit:** I am well aware that I don't need jQuery for a simple Ajax request, I just want to know if it's generally possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `importScripts` solve your problem? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries

That's how you would normally import a library in a Worker. However, in this case I think you'll still be out of luck importing jquery because jquery requires access to the DOM. See [HTML Web Worker and Jquery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838883/html-web-worker-and-jquery-ajax-call).

Comment: Although it does not solve my problem with jQuery, it's still what I was looking for. Thanks