# Can't import javascript libaries into web worker

Tags: javascript, import, web-worker

I cannot import any libraries into my javascript web worker using importScripts(). When I import my own separate javascript files it works fine but when I try and import a separate library such as jquery or easeljs it gives my the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

however it clearly is correctly defined after i have continuously checked it. Anybody know what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I think this answer also fits your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838883/html-web-worker-and-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's that the webworkers can't do a refer to the DOM, they can only communicate through messages to the caller script.
jQuery does an explicit reference to the DOM, so you can't use it in your webworker. I suggest you to have a look at this blog post from John Resig, the jQuery creator, about WebWorkers: http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/

Answer (score 2):

Web Workers have very limited access to DOM objects and methods, and are completely unable to access the global `document` object, which is required by both jQuery and easeljs.

I can't say for easel, but for jQuery there is a port of 1.6.3 which is compiled without the web worker-unsafe code. It can be found [here](https://github.com/kpozin/jquery-nodom).